# React Redux with ESLint rules

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, eslint, redux-thunk

in using React and Redux with Airbnb style and ESlint rules I have some confusions mostly about destructuring and upper scope:

```
import user from "./userModel";

class MyName extends Component {
  state = { user, size:0 };
render() {
    const {size}=this.state ; 
    const { username, items, location } = this.state.user;
    return (...)}}
MyName.propTypes = {createNewUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  // users: PropTypes.object};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({users: state.users});
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ createNewUser})(MyName);
```

in this code at destructuring the state, ESLint says `Must use destructuring state assignment (react/destructuring-assignment)`
and when I re-write it as

```
const {size, user}=this.state ; 
const { username, items, location } = user;
```

again I receive

```
'user' is already declared in the upper scope. (no-shadow)
```

the same type of warnings is shown in the when I deconstruct users(of the store) like `const {users}=this.props;` it says `'users' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)` and when I define it in propTypes, it says `object` is forbidden

Comment: It's hard to understand what you did with player since the code seems incomplete and inconsistent (sometimes you use state.player, some other times state.user, what about the upper scope?). I may be able to help you with complete (consistent) code example.
About propTypes if `PropTypes.object` is forbidden, you can try `PropTypes.instanceOf(user)` instead, or provide a shape "looking" like a user: `PropTypes.shape({ userName: PropTypes.string, items: ... }) `

Comment: @remix23 I am sorry it was a typo, there is a user object in local state and users in the store. In copy paste there was mistake. I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "rename" the variable while destructuring to prevent a conflict:

```
const { size, user: currentUser } = this.state;
```

The takes the value from `this.state.user` and assigns it to `currentUser`.

Comment: Thanks, the warning disappeared. but I did not see such a hint in the official documentation.

Comment: Is there a significant advantage gained with "react/destructuring-assignment" rule? With the forced renaming, its going to cause more, not fewer issues.

Comment: That's mostly a matter of opinion/context. If you had to rename everything, then it's probably not worth it. If you have to rename only 1 out of a number, then it's probably fine.